# Why are all the letter grade options in my code being shown when I run the program? I only want the correct answer shown

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java programming and was told this is a great site to push me in the right direction.

Why are all the letter grade options in my code being shown when I run the program? I only want the correct one shown. Please help.

Also, when typed out, how do I get the numeric value to display on the same line and not be returned down to the next line?

Thank you for any assistance and insight to Java newcomer.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package assignment_1;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment_1 
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Letter Grade Convertor Program");
        System.out.println();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String choice = "y";
        while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {

            System.out.println("Enter numerical grade: ");
            int grade = sc.nextInt();
            char letter = 0;
            if(grade <= 100 || grade >= 90)
                letter = 'A';
                System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);
            if (grade <= 89 || grade >= 80)
                letter = 'B';
                System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);

            if (grade <= 79 || grade >= 70)
                letter = 'C';
                System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);

            if(grade <= 69 || grade >= 60)
                letter = 'D';
                System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);

            if(grade < 60 || grade <=0)
                letter = 'F';
                System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);


            System.out.println("Continue? (y/n): ");
            choice = sc.next();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you only really need one println statement.  You could set the letter in the if statements and then do your `System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);` line on the line before you print the `Continue? (y/n):` prompt.

Comment: Check out the PrintStream javadoc and notice the difference between print(..) and println(..), println(..) terminates the line which might not be what you want if you want stuff on the same line.

Comment: Arrays and collections are great for simplifying your code, please check my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

you should add curly brackets if you have more than one statement. only first line belong to if condition if you leave brackets.so sout code get executed always. when you add curly brakes it is a block and all lines inside it belongs to if condition.

```
if(grade <= 100 || grade >= 90){
     letter = 'A';
     System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);
}
```

how ever is's good practice to always add curly brackets

however as @dici suggest you can print grade at the end instead adding out.print inside all if conditions

like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Letter Grade Convertor Program");
    System.out.println();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

        System.out.println("Enter numerical grade: ");
        int grade = sc.nextInt();
        char letter = 0;
        if (grade <= 100 || grade >= 90) {
            letter = 'A';
        }

        if (grade <= 89 || grade >= 80) {
            letter = 'B';
        }

        if (grade <= 79 || grade >= 70) {
            letter = 'C';
        }

        if (grade <= 69 || grade >= 60) {
            letter = 'D';
        }

        if (grade < 60 || grade <= 0) {
            letter = 'F';
        }
        System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);

        System.out.println("Continue? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.next();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just found that the shorter answer is actually a two-liner

Answer (score 1):

Use if-else if block for exclusive condition:

```
if (grade <= 100 || grade >= 90) {
     letter = 'A';
     System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);
} else if (grade <= 89 || grade >= 80) {
     letter = 'B';
     System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);
} else if (grade <= 79 || grade >= 70) {
     letter = 'C';
     System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);
} else if (grade <= 69 || grade >= 60) {
     letter = 'D';
     System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);
} else if(grade < 60 || grade <= 0) {
     letter = 'F';
     System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);
}
```

And these conditions can be optimized as below:

```
if (grade <= 100 || grade >= 90) {
     letter = 'A';
     System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);
} else if (grade >= 80) {
     letter = 'B';
     System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);
} else if (grade >= 70) {
     letter = 'C';
     System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);
} else if (grade >= 60) {
     letter = 'D';
     System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);
} else if(grade >= 0) {
     letter = 'F';
     System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);
}
```

In addition to above, for Dici's suggestion, you can avoid repeating `printlns`.

```
if (grade <= 100 || grade >= 90) {
     letter = 'A';
} else if (grade >= 80) {
     letter = 'B';
} else if (grade >= 70) {
     letter = 'C';
} else if (grade >= 60) {
     letter = 'D';
} else if(grade >= 0) {
     letter = 'F';
} else {
    // If you want to check illegal grade under 0 or over 100
    // throw new RuntimeException("The grade is out of range!");
}

System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);
```

Comment: You are always printing a grade, so you don't need to duplicate this part

Answer (score 1):

The letter grades are shown because you didn't use brackets.

In Java, if you don't use brackets for your `if` and `while` blocks, only the line immediately under it is considered attached to the `if`/`while`. What you're doing is essentially:

"If this grade matches this condition, set the letter to this", "Print the letter"

You should be looking for: "If this grade matches the condition, set the letter to this AND print the letter", which requires the use of brackets.

Which means the code you want is this:

```
if(grade <= 100 || grade >= 90) {
    letter = 'A';
    System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);
}
if (grade <= 89 || grade >= 80) {
    letter = 'B';
    System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);
}

if (grade <= 79 || grade >= 70) {
    letter = 'C';
    System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);
}

if(grade <= 69 || grade >= 60){
    letter = 'D';
    System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);
}

if(grade < 60 || grade <=0){
    letter = 'F';
    System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);
}
```

As a general note: Please always use brackets.

However, if you really don't want to use brackets, you can just remove the `System.out.println("Letter grade: " + letter);` line from each section, and put it once at the very end right before you ask for `Continue (y/n)`

Answer (score 1):

Everybody gave you a right answer already, so I'm not gonna repeat the part on the brackets. However, I will show you the most compact way (in the general case, because if the grades are linear you can do shorter) to write the exact same logic :

```
int[] intervals = { 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };
char[] grades = { 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A' };
int i = 0;

while (grade >= intervals[i] && i < intervals.length) i++;
System.out.println("Letter grade: " + grades[i]);
```

You can also do something a bit more obscure but shorter :

```
char[] grades = { 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A' };
System.out.println("Letter grade: " + grades[Math.max(0, (grade - 50) / 10)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The others fixed the syntax, but really quick, I wanted to point out the logic.

```
if (grade <= 100 || grade >= 90) {
 letter = 'A';
```

You are using the "||" operator which is the or operator. Thus, the program would always break out of the if else statements here because the grade will always be below 100. You could put 5 and it would say A. Shouldn't it be "&&", that way it will check the ranges you want?
Let me know if I'm missing something.